# Node.js force https to many redirects

Tags: node.js

Hi i wanted to make https the default route for my website.

I have the following code to make this happen

```
if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
  app.use (function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.secure){
      // request was via http, so redirect to https
      res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
    }
  });
}
```

Afterwards i have multiple routes like

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use("/de", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use("/de/home", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

If I do not use the redirect for https everything works fine. Where is my redirecting error?

Comment: Can we assume that you are listening on HTTPS?  Does it work if you browse on HTTPS?

Comment: no we cannot assume. i just wanted everybody to be redirected to https

Comment: Your server must listen on both HTTP and HTTPS for this to work

Answer (score 0):

You should turn your components into encoded URI components

```
if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
  app.use (function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.secure){
      // request was via http, so redirect to https
      res.redirect('https://' + encodeURIComponent(req.headers.host) + encodeURIComponent(req.url));
    }
  });
}
```

this should work just fine, i hope this helps

Comment: this is not work. if i log  wat is in the redirect i get ttps://localhost%3A3000%2F